# MongoDb NodeJs RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when pushing message

Tags: mongodb, angular, express, mongoose

I'm learning how to create a MEAN app and I'm having a problem when I try to push a message into a messages array in my User Model.
I can create a new message and pass the user object but when trying to pass the message object into the user.messages array I get an error in the console 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'.

I'll post my User and Message Models and the Message Route code.

Message Model

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let User = require('./user');


let schema = new Schema({
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', schema);
```

User Model

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let mongooseUniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

let schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    messages: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Message'
    }]
});

schema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

And my Route code

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
let User = require('../models/user');
let Message = require('../models/message');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    Message.find()
        .exec(function (err, messages) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Success',
                obj: messages
            });
        });
});

// Protect Routes
router.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    jwt.verify(req.query.token, 'secret', (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                title: 'Not Authenticated',
                error: err
            });
        }
        next();
    });
});

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
    User.findById(decoded.user._id, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }
        let message = new Message({
            content: req.body.content,
            user: user
        });
        message.save((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            }

            user.messages.push(result);
            user.save();
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Saved message',
                obj: result
            });
        });
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

I believe the problem comes form the post route

user.messages.push(result);

Thanks

Comment: I think you have a circular dependence on your User and Message Objects. You are calling user.save() inside of Message Object and also User is a property of the Message Object. I bet the problem comes there, could you show us the user.save() method ?

Comment: .save() it's a mongodb method to persist in the database. I still get the error even if I just push to the array without saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using refs in your schemas so you should store the **_id** value rather than the whole object:

```
...

let message = new Message({
  content: req.body.content,
  user: user._id
})

...
```

...and:

```
user.messages.push(result._id)
```

I hope this helps solve your problem.

Comment: I've tried that before but I get 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined' but I can log the user and it returns a value, and also it stores the userid in the message object.

Comment: It looks like you might not have a **messages** property if no messages have been previously added. Try adding a condition: if **messages** does not exist, set it to an array with just the new user id. If it does exist then use push.

Comment: You could also set a default value in your schema of an empty array. Docs here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html

Comment: I ended up fixing it by adding { usePushEach: true } to my User Model, Thanks for your help